# Что содержится в первой странице виртуальной памяти выделенной процессу?

Tags: linux, память, процесс

Вопрос в заголовке.

Пример:

```
root@N34300 test # cat /proc/14023/maps 
00400000-0041e000 r--p 00000000 08:01 654153                             /bin/bash
0041e000-0049c000 r-xp 0001e000 08:01 654153                             /bin/bash
0049c000-004cd000 r--p 0009c000 08:01 654153                             /bin/bash
004ce000-004d1000 r--p 000cd000 08:01 654153                             /bin/bash
004d1000-004da000 rw-p 000d0000 08:01 654153                             /bin/bash
004da000-004e4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
02152000-02194000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
```

В данном случае вопрос касается конкретно первых трех страниц. И почему, когда я перевожу начальные адреса виртуальных страниц в физические, иногда нахожу совпадения с другими процессами. То есть физические адреса начала первых страниц двух процессов могут совпадать.

```
00400000 -> 129f91000 (process1) 
00400000 -> 129f91000 (process2)
```

Comment: Из [map 5 proc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)  `For  ELF  files,  you  can easily coordinate with the offset field by looking at the  Offset field in the ELF program headers (readelf -l).` Посмотрев на вывод `readelf -f /bin/bash` -- `[Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000`   я бы сказал, что первые страницы процесса используются OS при выполнении `exec()` для обеспечения вызовов из динамических библиотек (.so) (хотя, imho там более 3-х страниц (обычно размер страницы 4К))

Comment: @avp то есть, получается, что два процесса использующие одну и ту же динамическую библиотеку могут иметь совпадающие страницы памяти?

Comment: Если _Динамическую **разделяемую** библиотеку_, то обязательно так и будет.

Comment: правильнее "то скорее всего так и будет". Но для кода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно, с адреса 00400000 загружается исполнимый код приложения. Так как у Вас два процесса похоже одинаковы (по всей видимости это баш), то ядро делает известную оптимизацию и использует один и тот же кусок памяти, что бы не делать дублирование данных в памяти. Точно также делают и другие ОС.
Так как эта память содержит исполнимый код, то она доступна только на чтение и ее никто так просто не поменяет. Если же кто то захочет снять такой признак, то память будет скопирована в отдельную физическую память и там уже будет модифицироваться.

Comment: хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение касательно новых созданных процессов. например pid 14302 и pid 14303 методом spawn (not fork). Физические адреса начала их страниц(первых трех) совпадают. Насколько я понимаю, вы описали механизм COW, который присущ форкам.

Comment: я конечно могу изобрести машину времени и ещё что то и посмотреть, что творится на Вашей машине и какие там процессы, но пока не хочу.

Comment: @kernelplv, в linux, что spawn, что fork реализуются одним и тем же syscall -- [clone](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html)

Comment: @KoVadim естественно, мне нет необходимости заставлять вас городить машину времени. Этими pid'ами я лишь хотел показать, что процессы были созданны практически в один момент, может это могло бы дать какую-то доп. информацию.
Хочу добавить, что смог найти еще немного [информации(pdf)](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch15.pdf) касательно первой страницы, и, да, там подтверждается, что в начале идет сегмент .text т.е. исполняемый код

Comment: то, что pid идут подряд, ещё ничего не значит. Абсолютно. Это могут быть два совершенно разных процесса.

Comment: @KoVadim хорошо, значит, я утверждаю, что эти процессы созданы в один момент т.к. я их создал сам.)

Comment: для Вас абсолютно очевидно, что это за процессы и как они созданы. Также Вам немного известны особенности Вашего окружения. У меня есть тысячи вариантов того, что могло произойти.